# runtime error for palindrome linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error, palindrome

I'm trying to solve the problem in leetcode for confirming the palindrome linked list([problem description](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/)). But there is always a runtime error when I check the linked list with even number of nodes.

The basic idea of my code is:
Use two pointers named `fast` and `slow` respectively. In a while loop use the `slow` pointer moving to the next nodes, and use the `fast` pointer moving to the next of the next nodes. When `fast` pointer reach the end of the list, the `slow` pointer should stay in the middle of the linked list. Reverse the half of the linked list behind the `slow` pointer and compare the item in the reversed linked list with the first half of the previous linked list one by one.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */

//https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/61648/o-n-time-and-o-1-space-4ms-java-solution
struct ListNode* reverse(struct ListNode* head) {
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return head;
    struct ListNode *rest = reverse(head->next);
    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;
    return rest;

}

bool isPalindrome(struct ListNode* head) {
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return true;
    struct ListNode *fast, *slow;
    fast = head;
    slow = head;
    while(fast->next != NULL && fast != NULL)
    {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }
    if(fast != NULL && fast->next == NULL)
        slow = slow->next;
    fast = head;
    struct ListNode *rest = reverse(slow);
    slow->next = NULL;
    while(fast != NULL && rest != NULL)
    {
        if(fast->val != rest->val)
        {
            return false;
        }
        fast = fast->next;
        rest = rest->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can someone help me to point out where the bug is? Thanks.

Comment: `fast->next != NULL && fast != NULL` --> `fast != NULL && fast->next != NULL `

Comment: If you run your code inside a debugger (such as gdb) it will tell you in what line the runtime error is coming from.